# Add application module dependency into another application module in Android Studio with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, module, dependencies

Is it possible to have 2 applications modules (with `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` at the head of their gradle file) and one having a dependency over another?

So module A would have a dependency to module B and both would be applications.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':moduleB')
}
```

I easily managed to add this dependency and no errors/warnings comes out but I still do not have access to source files inside moduleB. Android Stduio still suggest me to "add dependency to moduleB" and when I do it just re-syncing gradle and nothing happen.

I tried to include a dependency over a library module and this is working fine. Can't we add dependency between two (or more) applications modules?

Comment: Did you find anything on this issue?
I am facing the same problem.

Comment: No I decided not to use this mechanism but if you find a solution I'm curious to know about it.

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario in which you'd actually want that. You may think you do, but you don't. If you have common code that you want both application modules to depend on, you should extract that into a `com.android.library` project.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to have 2 applications modules (with apply plugin: 'com.android.application' at the head of their gradle file) and one having a dependency over another?

No, sorry.

> Can't we add dependency between two (or more) applications modules?

Correct — that is not supported.