# Unable to build gradle that depend on other module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Hey I have many modules in my project:

starting from low level **android library**

- logic

through the base **android application**

- base_app

```js
productFlavors{
   featureON{}
   featureOFF{}
}

buildTypes{
  release{}
  debug{}
}

dependencies{
  implementation project(':logic')
}
```

to the end user **android application**

- client app

```js
buildTypes{
  release{}
  debug{}
}

dependencies{
  implementation project(':base_app')
}
```

```
ext.gradle_version = '3.4.0'
```

I'm getting

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':client@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :base_app.
Show Details
Affected Modules: client

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':client@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :base_app.
Show Details
Affected Modules: client

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':client@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :base_app.
Show Details
Affected Modules: client

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':client@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :base_app.
Show Details
Affected Modules: client

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':client@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :base_app.
Show Details
Affected Modules: client
```

However if I use it as following

```
implementation project(path: ':app', configuration: 'default')
```

gradle runs, but in that case changing build variant debug/release doesn't change variant in app, what I required because I want to put more productFlavors in 'client' , namely `featureON{} featureOFF{}`

Related Questions:

- similiar issue [implementation project ':app' in 'libModule' not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53332289/2163045)
- include application module as dependency [Add application module dependency into another application module in Android Studio with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41854373/2163045)

Comment: android app will have following modules.                                                                                 https://developer.android.com/studio/projects

Answer (score 0):

android app will have following modules.

Android app module

Android Library(aar)

Android java library(jar)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ["*.jar"], dir: "libs")
    implementation fileTree(include: ["smack-*-${smackVersion}.jar"], dir: smackDir)
    implementation(name: "ion-${ionVersion}", ext: "aar")
}
```

We can not have more than one 'Android app module'.

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects